# What are the regulatory requirements requiring Weight and Balance be onboard aircraft for flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, weight-and-balance

The common mnemonic ARROW teaches private pilots a Weight and Balance must be onboard the aircraft for flight (usually included in the POH/AFM). What is the regulatory requirement for this?

In my research I've found a couple possible reasons but none current and regulatory.

- "W&B must be in the AFM as per 14 CFR 23.1583"

  - This regulation appears to be part of the [14 CFR 23 rewrite](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/understanding-part-23-rewrite) as it's no longer listed under part 23.
  - [14 CFR 23.2620](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/23.2620) states The Airplane Flight Manual must contain the following information (1) Airplane operating limitations;(2) Airplane operating procedures;(3) Performance information;(4) Loading information; and(5) Other information that is necessary for safe operation because of design, operating, or handling characteristics.
- "W&B must be onboard if required by the TCDS"

  - This may be both true and regulatory but in my case the TCDS only states the W&B be presented for Airworthiness Certification.
- "Weight and Balance is on the FAA ramp check inspection [checklist in chapter 56"](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8700.1%20GA%20Ops%20Insp%20Handbk/Volume%202/2_056_00.htm)

  - Is this checklist current and if so that doesn't make it regulatory.

Note there is potential for variations in semantics and at least 3 different interpretations of Weight and Balance.

- Weight and Balance data provided at certification
- Updated current Weight and Balance performed after aircraft alterations and equipment changes
- Weight and Balance loading calculations performed by the crew

Comment: Please reopen this. The other question contains out of date answers on Weight and Balance.

Comment: Hi Alex: If loading info should be in the AFM (per new 23 rewrite), and the AFM is required by the valid 91.1, then that solves it, right?

Comment: How do we interpret "Loading Information"